# Selecting the maximum discount percent of vouchers' price of every offer

Tags: mysql, laravel, greatest-n-per-group

I have two table `vouchers` and `offers`.

The fields of offer tables is `id, title`.

The fields of vouchers tables is `id, offer_id, title, original_price, off_price`.

The relation of between tables is **oneToMany**.

How to get top of maximum voucher percent, in every offer?

Comment: ' voucher percent, ?' would you like to define this?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $appends = ['max_discount_voucher'];
public function getMaxDiscountVoucherAttribute()
{
    return $this->vouchers
        ->select('*', \DB::raw('100 - ( new_price * 100 ) / old_price AS discount_percent'))
        ->orderByDesc('discount_percent')
        ->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) will be easy.

In your Offer model:

```php
protected $appends = ['max_discount'];

public function getMaxDiscountAttribute()
{
    return $this->vouchers()
               ->selectRaw('MAX(off_price - original_price) AS max_discount')
               ->first()
               ->max_discount;
}
```

And you can get the offers with this attribute like this:

```php
$offers = Offer::where(...)->get(); // return the eloquent.
$offers->first()->max_discount; // return the maximum discount
```

Comment: how to get list of offers that contain of the first max percent of vouchers?

Comment: @SaeedNikookalam have u built the relationship `vouchers()`?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeees

Comment: @SaeedNikookalam ok, how do u know it is not working. is there any error message?  can u give me some info?

Comment: when the append the max_discount field the result no changed.

Comment: @SaeedNikookalam u can loop it, and call that attribute by `->max_discount`, or u can convert it to json, you will see it. like `Offer::where(...)->get()->toJson()`

Comment: So if u r using render view, u can use @foreach to get that. If you are using json, you still can get that, it's convenient. And this is accessor.@SaeedNikookalam

Comment: OK, but i'm not access the voucher of each offer that those have maximum discount percent

Comment: @SaeedNikookalam but you still access the voucher of each offer  from the answer you posted...